# Set SQLite as database for unit testing in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to set-up unit testing in Laravel 5.1. Following the [**documentation**](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing) I see this:

> Laravel is built with testing in mind. In fact, support for testing
>   with PHPUnit is included out of the box

and

> When running tests, Laravel will automatically set the configuration
>   environment to testing. Laravel automatically configures the session
>   and cache to the array driver while testing, meaning no session or
>   cache data will be persisted while testing.

which is awesome. But... **how do I tell Laravel to use SQLite database connection when tests are ran?**

Only thing there is in config/database.php is this commented code:

```
/* We might use this connection for unit tests
'sqlite' => [
    'driver'   => 'sqlite',
    'database' => storage_path().'/database.sqlite',
    'prefix'   => '',
],
*/
```

*We might use this* :)

Is there a way to set this globally for all test? Do I need to set the connecton in every test case?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Actually it's pretty simple.

Create a testing database on your `storage/` folder, with the name `database.sqlite` or if you want another name or another location you have to change the configs on the `config/database.php` file, these are the default configs:

```
'sqlite' => [
    'driver'   => 'sqlite',
    'database' => storage_path('database.sqlite'),
    'prefix'   => '',
],
```

You have two options, you either edit your `.env` or you just specify the name of the database where you want to run your migrations:

```
php artisan migrate --database=sqlite
```

If you prefer editing your `.env` file, then we have to add a new variable:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
```

That's because Laravel defaults to MySQL when this variable is absent from `.env` file:

```
//config/database.php file
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

Now that our app is pointing into our sqlite database we can now run our migrations and seeding. After that if you just want to keep running MySQL remove `DB_CONNECTION=sqlite` from the `.env` file.

Now that you have your migrations on your testing database the last step is just to specify, your SQLite as your default database for tests.

On your root folder you have a `phpunit.xml` file, open it and a new variable under `<php>` node:

```
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
```

Now your application is using MySQL and **phpunit** is using SQLite.

**Remember** that if you change the `.env` to change it back to your default database;

### PS

Be careful when running your migrations, if you specified a connection on the migration itself, it will try to run it on that connection.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AdminUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::connection('manage')->create('admin_users', function (Blueprint $t) {
            $t->increments('id');
            $t->string('name');
            $t->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::connection('manage')->dropIfExists('admin_users');
    }
}
```

This migration will always run on the connection **manage** no matter what you specify on the `.env` file or in the migration command

Comment: Glad I could help you out.

Comment: Works after `sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite`

Comment: @Ryu_hayabusa if you don't have have the sqlite PDO driver, then yes, you have to install it first

Answer (score 11):

I have a bit of a different solution. I am using an in memory sqlite database.

first I change the default and then add a new connection to the database.php in config

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

...

'testing' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlite',
    'database' => ':memory:',
    'prefix' => '',
],
```

then I add the following line to the phpunit.xml

```
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="testing"/>
```

I leave the .env file untouched. That way the database connection will default to 'mysql'

---

Here is the full phpunit.xml for more clarity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnFailure="false"
     syntaxCheck="false">
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory>./tests/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
<filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory suffix=".php">app/</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
<logging>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="./report/" charset="UTF-8"
         yui="true" highlight="false" 
         lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80"/>
</logging>    
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="testing"/>
</php>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: I can't for the life of me fathom why this won't work for me. I've done the exact same thing but yet tests are still running against my local db. Tried `php artisan config:clear` as well with no joy

Comment: Hi Steven, I've added the whole phpunit.xml to the answer, maybe that will help see why it is not working

Comment: Thanks. I found creating a `.env.testing` file to be the only thing that worked.

Comment: Do not use in memory sqlite when testing! I use dusk for testing and since it runs in a different process the database for dusk is different than the database your website is using! Keep that in mind.