# Laravel 4 unittest using wrong database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit

I have created a testing database environment as follows:

```
return array(

    'default' => 'sqlite',

    'connections' => array(
        'sqlite' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:',
            'prefix'   => ''
        ),
    )
);
```

When I initialise my database in my setUp function this all appears to work fine:

```
Mail::pretend(true);
Artisan::call('migrate');

$this->seed();
```

Any query directly in my test directly in my test class returns what I would expect however if I call a function on my model that does anything with the database it uses my 'live' (I'm running this in a vagrant dev server so no risk of ruining anything) database instead of my test one. Do I need to change my configuration further to ensure it is using my test database? Or do I need to instantiate my model in a special way?

An example of what doesn't work. In my test:

```
// gets the correct company
$comp = Companies::find(1);
// gets results from wrong database
$comp->quotesAndOrders();
```

where quotesAndOrders does a simple query on a hasMany relationship (orders)

```
$this->orders()->get();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set SQLite as database for unit testing in Laravel 5.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132270/set-sqlite-as-database-for-unit-testing-in-laravel-5-1)

Comment: This is Laravel 4, sorry. I thought I had put that but I had only put it in the tags. Updated the title to make it clearer

Comment: Oh in that case I have removed the duplicate vote, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

First of all on our .env file we have to add a new variable.
looks like this.

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
```

That's because of  Laravel defaults to MySQL when this variable is absent from .env file:

**see here..**

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql')
```

Now that our app is pointing into our `sqlite` database we can now run our `migrations` and `seeding`. After that if you just want to keep running `MySQL` remove `DB_CONNECTION=sqlite` from the .env file.

Now on your root folder you have a `phpunit.xml` file, open it and a new variable under `<php>` node

```
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
```

Comment: This is laravel 4 sorry it wasn't clear. I have tried adding db connection to my .env.testing.php but it makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

This project is based on someone elses code originally. In my companies model (annoyingly no other class and this was the first one I tested otherwise I would have spotted it sooner) there is an explicit definition to use the mysql database. I'm not sure why this was. I have removed that line and it now works.